# ValueError: could not convert string to float while implementing sklearn

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am new in this, I am getting some error like this ;

```
 File "C:\Users\Himanshu\Desktop\Project\ML\Pract\mlp1.py", line 268, in 
 <module> cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, 
 cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
 File "C:\Users\Himanshu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-  
 packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 402, in cross_val_score
 error_score=error_score)
 .
 .
 etc..like above)
 ValueError: could not convert string to float: transact
```

the shape of the dataset I am using is (30,216)

```
array = dataset.values
X = array[:,0:215]
Y = array[:,215]
validation_size = 0.20
seed = 7
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = 
model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=validation_size, 
random_state=seed)
```

I want to know, am I Splitting it correctly or not.
Can someone please suggest why this error is occurring.

**Edited:**
I am adding the rest of the code :

```
scoring = 'accuracy'

# Spot Check Algorithms
models = []
models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression()))
models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('SVM', SVC()))
# evaluate each model in turn
results = []
names = []
for name, model in models:
kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, 
cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
results.append(cv_results)
names.append(name)
msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
print(msg)
```

Comment: You have some string values in your data `X_train`. Convert them to numbers